# Can't load Webapp (Spring 3.2.0RC2, Tomcat 7.0.27)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I got problems starting my Webapp using Spring MVC 3.2.0, Tomcat 7.0.27 in Eclipse Indigo. Everything worked fine since yesterday. But now it seems that my Webapp won't deploy correctly.

```
...
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 477 ms
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.27
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory <...>.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\...
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-80"]
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jan 06, 2013 12:04:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2800 ms
```

Only the message

> INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

feels to me that there are problems deploying the webapp

When I call the URL

localhost:8080/myWebApp

I only see the directory listing

What I have done:
I removed the `source` property of my webApp from the `server.xml` and my `/WEB-INF/web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>        

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I placed the servlet-definition into `/WEB-INF` and it looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
    xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
                        http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="net.tud.vorlesung" />


    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

Comment: A project clean and eclipse/servers/"clean..."  often helps in situations like this.

Comment: I solved my problem by starting from the scratch in a new Workspace. Clean Eclipse and Servers didn't work. At least Spring gives a feedback in the console about Requestmapping when using Annotationdriven MVC ;) Thanks at lasat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has occurred to me when I opened a project from a upgraded IDE into a old one, So this help me to solve the issue `Right Click on my project -> Maven -> Update Project...`

Answer (score 1):

To get this question solved, I gonna describe how I fixed my own Problem.

At least the problem was the publishing of my project into my local server, I guess not all built classes have been deployed.

With the usage of Maven, it seems to be necessary to add your maven-lib package to your projects deployment assembly (Project > right click > properties > deployment assembly).

Additionally if your console shows NoClassDef-Exception you should "clean" your Serverdeployment. This can be done with Eclipse (I use Juno). Just right-click on your server and click on "Clean...".

How long your redeployment takes depends on your Project. In my project it takes >5 Minutes.

If this doesn't work, try first to use "real" JARs instead of Maven.
Actually I had a problem with Jena (see  [Sparql Select Query works on Sesame-Workbench but not on Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594533/sparql-select-query-works-on-sesame-workbench-but-not-on-java))

Hope this will help a lot of people.

Comment: I don't know if it will help a lot of people, but it surely help me!