# Sparql Select Query works on Sesame-Workbench but not on Java

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, sesame

I'm trying to create a Sparql-Query to get all messages, that are related to a lecture. I'm new at the whole 'semantic web'-story so be patient if the usage namespace is completely wrong.

The query I try to execute is:

```
PREFIX siocNS: <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#>
PREFIX rdfPred: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX purlPred: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX purlPredLecture: <http://purl.org/<CENSORED>/lecture/>
select ?post ?title ?content ?time ?creator where
{
  ?post rdfPred:type siocNS:Post.
  ?post purlPred:title ?title. 
  ?post purlPred:content ?content. 
  ?post purlPred:created ?time. 
  ?post purlPred:creator ?creator.
  ?post purlPred:context purlPredLecture:1337-7331.
}
```

where `1337-7331` is an ID.

On Sesame-Workbench the query seems working fine (because I get my 2 expected rows). On Java ,using Jena, it seems that my `QueryExecuion` isn't correct.

Here my code:

```
String prefix = "PREFIX siocNS: <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX rdfPred: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX purlPred: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>\n"
            + "PREFIX purlPredLecture: <http://purl.org/<CENSORED>/lecture/>\n";
String queryString = "select ?post ?title ?content ?time ?creator where\n"
        + "{\n"
        + "?post rdfPred:type siocNS:Post.\n"
        + "?post purlPred:title ?title. \n"
        + "?post purlPred:content ?content. \n"
        + "?post purlPred:created ?time. \n"
        + "?post purlPred:creator ?creator.\n"
        + "?post purlPred:context purlPredLecture:"
        + lectureID + ".\n" + "}";
logger.info("Created Query:" + prefix + queryString);

Query query = QueryFactory.create(prefix
        + queryString, Syntax.syntaxSPARQL);
query.addResultVar("?post");
query.addResultVar("?title");
query.addResultVar("?content");
query.addResultVar("?time");
query.addResultVar("?creator");
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

QueryExecution execution = QueryExecutionFactory
        .create(query, model);
ResultSet execSelect = execution.execSelect();
while (execSelect.hasNext()) {
...        
DO SOME STUFF
...
}
```

The query shown above was copied from the java-debugger. Did I missed something on preparation of the `Query(Execution)` and does Sesame-Workbench complete missing things?

Thx for your help!

dpa

Comment: what is the exception you are getting?
what is the value of lectureID ?

Comment: I didnt get any exception. After executing 'execution.execSelect();' the ResultSet is empty. The value of lectureID is 1337-7113 (same as in the query)

Comment: OMG now i see what is missing... missed setting up the server (including ReposiotryID). But didn't see any possibilities to setup these informations. Any help for this?

Comment: Okay I solved my problem. Due I use opensesame I used its JAR as well for creating my queue. Works perfectly. Thx for all at least

Comment: please post your solution as answer here and accept it so that your question will not be marked as "unanswered" and others can learn from your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So my solution for my own problem ;)

```
String prefix = "PREFIX siocNS: <http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX rdfPred: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>\n"
            + "PREFIX purlPred: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>\n"
            + "PREFIX purlPredLecture: <http://purl.org/<CENSORED>/lecture/>\n";
String queryString = "select ?post ?title ?content ?time ?creator where\n"
        + "{\n"
        + "?post rdfPred:type siocNS:Post.\n"
        + "?post purlPred:title ?title. \n"
        + "?post purlPred:content ?content. \n"
        + "?post purlPred:created ?time. \n"
        + "?post purlPred:creator ?creator.\n"
        + "?post purlPred:context purlPredLecture:"
        + lectureID + ".\n" + "}";
logger.info("Created Query:" + prefix + queryString);
String completeQuery = prefix + queryString;
        logger.info("Created Query:\n" + completeQuery);
        RepositoryConnection con = createRepositoryConnection();
        if (con == null) {
            logger.warn("Error creating repository connection. Returning epty list");
            return new ArrayList<UserMessage>();
        }
        ArrayList<UserMessage> messages = new ArrayList<UserMessage>();
    try {
        try {
            TupleQuery prepareTupleQuery = con
                    .prepareTupleQuery(
                            QueryLanguage.SPARQL,
                            completeQuery);
            TupleQueryResult result = prepareTupleQuery
                    .evaluate();
            while (result.hasNext()) {
               ...
            }
            for (UserMessage message : messages) {
                collectReplysOfMessage(lectureID,
                        message.getId());
            }
        } catch (MalformedQueryException e) {
            logger.error("Malformed Exception caught",
                    e);
        } catch (QueryEvaluationException e) {
            logger.error(
                    "Error on evaluating the query", e);
        } finally {
            con.close();
        }
    } catch (RepositoryException e) {
        logger.error(
                "Error on creationg repository connection",
                e);
    }
```

Where 'createRepositoryConnection()' looks like

```
private static RepositoryConnection createRepositoryConnection() {
        if (repoistory == null) {
            prepareRepository();
        }
        RepositoryConnection con = null;
        try {
            con = repoistory.getConnection();
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            logger.error(
                    "Error on creating repository connection",
                    e);
        }
        return con;
    }
```